# DropDownListFor Helper from generic IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a project using DDD and MvC3 with razor within this project have one Generic class Entity:

```
public class Entity
{

   public long Id{ get; set;}

}
```

And other class :

```
public class Categories : Entity
{

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set;}
}
```

and other classes that inherit from Categories, Ex:

```
 public class VideoCategory : Categories
    {
     // no have aditional proprieties
    }
```

Need to create a Helper establishing a DropDownList from a `IEnumerable<Categories>`.

I have a BaseRepository that returns a list of any kind, I would use it to accelerate.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: Entity
{

protected DbContext DbContext
        {
            get
            {
                return DependencyResolver.Get<IDbContext>() as DbContext;
            }
        }

 public virtual IList<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<TEntity>)this.DbSet).Where(x => x.Deleted == false).OrderByDescending(item => item.Id).ToList();
        }

}
```

and a repository for each entity, Ex :

```
public class VideoRepository : BaseRepository<VideoCategory >
    {
    }
```

so I can use the repository to the list obeter in a generic class

Comment: I've tried using a catalytic method for class and a property in viewmodel with the list of categories, but I'm trying a Helper that passing the IEnumerable return the DropDown, I'll make a note in question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public long SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and then assuming you have a collection of categories populate the view model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = new[]
        {
            new Categories { Id = 1, Name = "cat 1" },
            new VideoCategory { Id = 2, Name = "cat 2" },
        };

        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Categories = categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally build the corresponding dropdown list in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)
```

Comment: Have used this way but in all categories gotta make a method to generate a list of them, like a method genério, I made an Enum but I could not from an IEnumerable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain better. I have several classes inheriting from a parent class for each category have a repository that also inherit from a base class, or can I use this base class passing the desired type that it returns me a list, I need a Helper that passing the type , go to the repository manages the list and fill a dropdownlist.